# Script to assign a class on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onload

This is rather simple question. But I have been unable to fix.
I created this lab website: http://www-plb.ucdavis.edu/Labs/sundar/
I want the "Home" navigation button to turn golden when the page loads, without needing to click on the button.

I wrote a JQuery function to assign a class that makes the current page on the navigation golden color as below. But this happens only on click. I want the active class to be assigned on load. Thank you!

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#nav a').each(function(index) {
        if(this.href.trim() == window.location)
            $(this).addClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post a minimum HTML example to go with this, perhaps in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your 'Home' button does not turn golden brown on page load is because the link for that button is `http://www-plb.ucdavis.edu/Labs/sundar/index.html` while the current page is `http://www-plb.ucdavis.edu/Labs/sundar/`, so the check for `this.href.trim() == window.location` fails.

You can fix this by changing the link for the Home button from

```
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
```

to

```
<a href="http://www-plb.ucdavis.edu/Labs/sundar/">Home</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#nav a').each(function(index) {
    console.log(this.href.trim());
    console.log(window.location.toString());
});
```

If I run the code at http://www-plb.ucdavis.edu/Labs/sundar/

> http://www-plb.ucdavis.edu/Labs/sundar/index.html
>
> http://www-plb.ucdavis.edu/Labs/sundar/
>
> ...

If I run the code at 'Home' (http://www-plb.ucdavis.edu/Labs/sundar/index.html)

> http://www-plb.ucdavis.edu/Labs/sundar/index.html
>
> http://www-plb.ucdavis.edu/Labs/sundar/index.html
>
> ...

So, simply you have a wrong code.

Why don't you put class `active` on each html manually?